# Return Result with unquoted string

Tags: string, error-handling, rust, quotes

If I have a file like this:

```
use std::error::Error;
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {   

   Err("May
June")?

}
```

I get this result:

```
Error: "May\nJune"
```

Is it possible to get the unquoted string on output? Like this:

```
Error: May
June
```

I tried this:

```
Err("May
June").map_err(|e|
   format!("{:?}", e)
)?
```

but it just made it worse:

```
Error: "\"May\\nJune\""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to print the error yourself instead of relying on the default fallback implementation.

`main() -> Result<…>` prints `Debug` version of the error (where strings are escaped). It's intended as a quick'n'dirty solution for examples or playpens, and not for real programs where anyone would care about presentation of the output.

Use:

```rust
fn main() {
   if let Err(e) = run() {
       eprintln!("{}", e);
       std::process::exit(1);
   }
}

fn run() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   // etc
}
```

It will print the error using `Display` formatting.

There's nothing special about `main()`'s built-in error handling, so you're not losing anything by printing the error yourself.

There's also an alternative solution of implementing a custom `Debug` implementation on errors to make the `Debug` implementation print a non-debug one, but IMHO that's a hack, and needs more code than just doing the straightforward print. If you want that hack, have a look at [the `anyhow` crate](https://lib.rs/crates/anyhow).

Comment: Thanks. I was originally doing pretty much this, but then I thought why print and exit, when I could just return an error. Full circle.

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill to pull in an extra dependency for this, but you can use the [`terminator`](https://docs.rs/terminator/) crate, which offers a new error type intended to be returned from `main` that delegates to the `Display` implementation when printed with `Debug`. Then your example would look like this...

```
use terminator::Terminator;

fn main() -> Result<(), Terminator> {   
   Err("May
June")?
}
```

...and the output would be this:

```
Error: May
June
```